# Scala instantiate class and invoke method

Tags: scala

I've seen code that instantiates a class and invokes a method in that class on the same line such as:

```
(new className).method(parameter1, parameter2)
```

What is the above concept called and how does it work?

Comment: What do you mean with concept?, I would just call it: "instantiate class and invoke method". - Also, what do you mean with how does it work?, it just instantiate the class a call a method from it. - Am I missing something? **Note:** I hope I don't sound mean, is not my intention _(However it gives me the impression I sound cold when writting in English)_, I am really just curios what is weird about the above?

Comment: yea, good point. So, this only works when I wrap a parentheses around the class, right?

Comment: Yes, I mean if you do this `val classInstance = new className` and then this `classInstance.method(parameter1, parameter2)` at the end just means "call the method `method` from this instance `classInstance` of the class `className` passing some parameters" - at the end, for calling a method you need the reference of the object in which you call the method. At the end the parentheses are just to encapsulate the reference of the new instantiated class, that is needed because the `.` operator has a higher precedence that the `new` keyword I think.

Comment: I don't think that parenthesis are required at all.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Parentheses are required if the method invocation could be confused with a member type. E.g. given `class Foo { def bar = 42 }`, you can write `new Foo().bar` without parens, but you need the parens in `(new Foo).bar`, because otherwise the compiler would try to find a value `Foo` and instantiate an instance of a nested class `bar`, as e.g. in `object Foo { class bar } ; new Foo.bar`. I fail to see what's so interesting about this particular case. It's just the usual "if there is ambiguity, use parentheses to disambiguate".